# Extending Interface in TypeScript where module=es6 results in Property does not exist

Tags: typescript

When I try and switch from `"module": "commonjs",` to `"module: "es6",` in my tsconfig.json, I can no longer compile the following code due to the following errors:

> models/Combined.ts(12,9): error TS2322: Type '{ 'name': any; 'date':
>   Date; 'occupation': any; }' is not assignable to type 'Combined'.
>   Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''name'' does
>   not exist in type 'Combined'.
>
> models/Combined.ts(22,23): error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Combined'.

models/Combined.ts:

```
import {
    Simple
} from './';


export interface Combined extends Simple {
    occupation?: string;
}

export function CombinedFromJSON(json: any): Combined {
    return {
        'name': json['Name'],
        'date': !exists(json, 'Date') ? undefined : new Date(json['Date']),
        'occupation': !exists(json, 'Occupation') ? undefined : json['Occupation'],
    };
}

export function CombinedToJSON(value?: Combined): any {
    if (value === undefined) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return {
        'Name': value.name,
        'Occupation': value.occupation,
    };
}
```

models/Simple.ts

```
export interface Simple {
    name: string;
    readonly date?: Date;
}
```

I've read through a few SO questions similar to this and the [interfaces page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) from typescript website but I am still scratching my head on this one. It appears this should work, and indeed it does when the target module system is `commonjs`. tslint doesn't complain at all when developing and I've tried both TS 2.4 and 3.1 with no luck.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28687#issuecomment-442167850

I needed to add `"moduleResolution" : "node"` to my tsconfig.json